# Disable 'Search Settings' button while in kiosk mode android

Tags: java, android, kiosk-mode

I currently have an android app that is currently running in Kiosk Mode. The app is running as a system app on a rooted android phone. I want to let the user change the Time/Time-zone, so I am redirecting them to the 'Date & Time' settings page. However, the user's are able to go into the settings and change things by tapping the magnifying glass.

Is there a way to disable these buttons?
[Date & Time page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO7J7.jpg)